# How to listen to webview url click and enable/disable buttons on actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-webview, webviewclient

I'm developing an application in which I'm using `webview` to load certain websites. I also have customized `actionbar` on which I have website navigation `button`. Here is the view how my layout is looking like:

[image: How it looks to me.]

When I load website my all three buttons are visible, but I want them to be visible at that time only when user has clicked on some URL, so user easily understand the purpose of those buttons.

I have added all the functionalities to those button. Here is my code:

```
website_back = (ImageButton) cView.findViewById(R.id.website_back);
website_forward = (ImageButton) cView.findViewById(R.id.website_forward);
website_refresh = (ImageButton) cView.findViewById(R.id.website_refresh);

if (v.getId() == R.id.website_back) {
    webview.goBack();
}
if (v.getId() == R.id.website_forward) {
    webview.goForward();
}
if (v.getId() == R.id.website_refresh) {
    webview.reload();
}
```

My WebViewClient:

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        website_back.setImageResource(R.drawable.webview_back);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I only show those buttons when user has clicked on some URL, on the website launched in the webview?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you managing the web history of the user. If you are using some data structure (like a Arraylist or something) you can check the availability of the data in the data structure and where are you currently on the data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to attach a WebViewClient to the WebView to listen in on the URLs that are being fetched.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.equals(mOriginalUrl)){
            //initial url load, ignoring.
        }
        else {
            //url was navigated to - do something
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //page has finished loading
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see my edited question. I have already used that. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is always called on first load of the URL. What can I do that it should load only when user has clicked somewhere in the `webivew.`

Comment: assuming you are actually throwing the url in yourself, within shouldOverrideUrlLoading, do a string match against the url you passed in and ignore it if it is true.

Comment: What will be `mOriginalUrl`?

Comment: You said you are opening the webview to the user with an URL that you provide, the initial url. mOriginalUrl is that URL.

Comment: By doing this my original URL is also not loading. Else is executed then. My if condition do not.

Comment: The if else block in my provided code does not interfere with the return statement. Only if you interfere with the return statement is it going to prevent the webview from loading the provided url.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. hope it would be useful for you. try this

ExternalSiteActivity.class

```
public class ExternalSiteActivity extends Activity{
WebView webView;
String productURL;
ProgressBar progressBar;
ImageButton webBackButton;
ImageButton webForwButton;
ImageButton webRefreshButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.external_site_activity);
    productURL= (String) getIntent().getStringExtra("productUrl");
    System.out.println(productURL+"**********");
    progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webBackButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.web_back_button);
    webForwButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.web_forw_button);
    webRefreshButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.web_refresh_button);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(productURL);
    webBackButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(webView.canGoBack())
                webView.goBack();
        }
    });
    webForwButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(webView.canGoForward())
                webView.goForward();
        }
    });
    webRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.reload();
        }
    });
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        Log.v("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend,
            Message resend) {
        Log.v("onFormResubmission", "onFormResubmission");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webBackButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            webBackButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(webView.canGoForward())
        {
            webForwButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            webForwButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.v("onPageStarted", "onPageStarted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.v("on load ","load resources----");
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}